# Using GIT to push to several node instances in docker containers

Tags: git, docker, node.js

I am planning to setup a Docker environment with several docker containers for various services. These services include a few node instances of the same website.

I develop on my local machine and would like to push finished code to all of the node instances at the same time.

I've done this for a single container before by installing git in the container and pushing directly to it. I could in theory install git on all of the node instance containers and do so. But that seems like more work. I have however also needed openssh in each container to do so.

I was wondering is it possible for all of the containers to share persistent data on the host (where the website files would be) and have git installed on the host for I can push to it from my local machine.

In the future I will also be setting up several servers with their own farms of node instances. So pushing to multiple servers which themselves contain multiple node containers is how it will look like.

Are there any standard ways of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering is it possible for all of the containers to share
>   persistent data on the host (where the website files would be) and
>   have git installed on the host for I can push to it from my local
>   machine.

Sure - just share a host volume (`docker run -v /path/to/host/folder:/path/to/container/folder`) with each container.